# Best source control for maintaining devel. and prod. versions of a project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, svn

What is the best way to manage a devel. and prod. versions of a Java project?

Currently I use SVN and I have 1 working copy and 1 source folder on SVN. `The problem is I always work on the same sources and I want 2 sources: 1 with stable code and 1 with new features that are under development. After the devel. code is finished I want to merge with the prod. sources.`

Please help me with some tutorial or something. I heard about branches/trunk but don't know exactly what that means.

I'm open to use Git if that's more suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN also can fullfill your needs. If you are using eclipse just incorporate SVN URL. You will get easy options to create branchs there

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about branches. Git is fastly becoming the industry standard for version control so I would recommend switching to git and learn in that environment. Git and SVN has different views on many things including branches.

Branches can be used in many different way to tackle you problem. The most common strategy is to use the main branch for the code currently deployed. This branch is called `trunk` in SVN and almost always called `master` in git.

Branches for development comes in many flavours. One take is to have a long living branch for development that is merged into master whenever it is time to do a new release. Another take is to create new feature branches for each new feature to develop. Sometimes these two strategies are used together - most often when several developers work on the same repository. Pick the strategy that works best for your case.